# Are questions about microscope equipment on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

In example the following question:

- [Is the attached digital camera on the top have the same magnification than visible in eyepiece?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23404/1195)

Seems to be off-topic on biology SE, does the same question would be on-topic here?

It seems there are already some questions related to [microscopy](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microscopy) (including [microscope equipment](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/53963/10887)).

Answer (score 3):

I think that particular question is borderline. Microscopy does involve photography. It may not necessarily be an artistic form of photography, but not all photography is (although some microscope images today are both incredible scientifically and quite beautiful.)

I think the question could be migrated here, and we can see if it gets any useful answers. There ARE answers to that question, however I believe more information would be required before good answers could really be provided, because as-worded, I think they may be rather subjective.